OLS - How to create a good feature
I'm working on trying to predict the next price return for a stock given the inside bid-ask volumes (level 1 data) and I want to create a feature that models the imbalance between bid volumes and ask volumes, with the general hypothesis being when there is higher bid volume, the price returns are going to be higher. I'm using basic OLS
I have two ideas in mind and I'm not sure which is better, or how to even evaluate the two's merits.
Assume the inside bid volume is $b$, and the inside ask volume is $a$
First Equation:
$\frac{b}{b+a}$
Second Equation:
$\frac{b-a}{b+a}$

Now obviously the second equation is just a linear transformation (1-X) of the other, so I can't use both.
My question is: does it matter which I use? In my head, the latter is better because it ranges from [-1,1] versus the first one which ranges from [0,1] only. In a univariate regression, the bias term takes care of the difference. But does that apply to multivariate?
I'm trying to learn why there would or wouldn't be a difference, so any help is appreciated :)

I want to create a feature that models that imbalance. What imbalance?

a feature that models the imbalance between bid volume and ask volume. cleared up the wording of my question

FWIW, the second formula is $2X-1,$ not $1-X.$ But it doesn't matter, because both expressions lie in the space spanned by $1$ and $X$ and therefore do not change the multiple regression.  There can be numerical issues with the solution, but that's a different matter.

Hi: you can do 1 -  (2 * ( bid * bid volume) / [( bid * ask volume ) + ( ask * ask volume )]). This way, you get -1 when it's all bid volume and +1 when it's all ask volume. Not sure if that's what you were looking for ?

Not sure if this is still relevant but I read it a looooong time ago when I was working on this type of thing.  It used to be free so it still might be free somewhere. The one I'm pointing to is not. https://pure.psu.edu/en/publications/the-information-content-of-an-open-limit-order-book

@whuber can you elaborate on this? I feel like the numerical issues are something I am lost at as well
